# Maven eclipse:eclipse not generating .project

Tags: eclipse, maven

In my multi project module, when I run the `eclipse:eclipse` I notice that quite a few projects do not have the .project files and hence not appearing in the Eclipse.

Do I need to configure any in these POM?

Comment: What's the output of mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I am no eclipse expert but I believe you can use the m2e plugin instead of using `maven-eclipse-plugin`.

If you have that plugin installed then you can just do `[File] -> [Import...]`. That will bring up a in import dialog. If you go to the `[Maven]` folder and open it you will be able to select `Existing Maven Projects`.

I think that both ways (`maven-eclipse-plugin` and `m2e`) has their positive and negative aspects. But you could at least try the `m2e` plugin and see if there is a difference.